# VertX Sync issue - Method called not from within a fiber

Tags: java, synchronization, vert.x

I can't seem to get VertX Sync working. I just get the 'method not called from within fiber' exception everytime

In my verticle...

```
public class CVEVerticle extends SyncVerticle {

private MongoClient mongo;

@Override
@Suspendable
public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    mongo = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, config());
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.get("/api/processStats").handler(Sync.fiberHandler(this::processStats));     


    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(
        // Retrieve the port from the configuration, default to 8080.
        config().getInteger("http.port", 8084), result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                fut.complete();
            } else {
                fut.fail(result.cause());
            }
        });
}

@Suspendable
public void processStats(RoutingContext routingContext) {
     // do some stuff
     Sync.awaitResult(h -> process("test", h));
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-sync</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not sure why it isn't working, I've passed in the quasar-core jar in -javaagent when launching the fat jar. Any ideas?

cheers
Martin

Comment: `vertx.createHttpServer()` created a separate work thread so in fact `fut` will not be called from within the fibre.

Comment: Can you include a stack trace?

Comment: Just tested this and got no exception.

Comment: Thank you for looking, I found my problem this morning. In the processStats method the sync.awaitresult method was being called from a lambda handler in a mongodb client call. This handler was not being treated as a fiberhandler so it was throwing an exception.

Comment: OK cool. Glad that's figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Also you hide code in `SyncVerticle.start(Future)` method. Override `SyncVerticle.start()` instead.

See [Vertx-Sync documentation (SyncVerticle)](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sync/java/#_syncverticle) for details.